# Django modal autoimplement

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, autocomplete, modal-dialog

Can anyone advise on how to deal with retrieving data from other models in Django? I was able to put information with the name of the company in the form, but after choosing from dropdown, I would like the tax identification number from database to be completed automatically. The problem is both the automatic completion and the binding and extraction of data.

p[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3TJ7.png
p[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZYAG.png

Model:

```
klient_lista = Klient.objects.all().values_list("nazwa_firmy", "nazwa_firmy")

class Faktura(models.Model):
    numer = models.CharField(max_length=260, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    klient = models.CharField(max_length=260, choices=klient_lista)
    NIP = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    kwota_netto = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    VAT = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    kwota_brutto = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
```

views:

```
@login_required
def Faktury(request):
    faktura = Faktura.objects.all()
    faktura_Form = Faktura_Form(request.POST or None)
    if faktura_Form.is_valid():
        faktura_Form.save()
        return redirect(Faktury)
    return render(request, 'Faktury.html', {'form': Faktura_Form, 'faktura': faktura})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store klient objects in a variable instead use foreign key to connect the two tables. I hope you refer to the "number" field by tax identification number and it is defined in klient model.

```
class Faktura(models.Model):
    klient = models.ForeignKey(Klient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    NIP = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    kwota_netto = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    VAT = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    kwota_brutto = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
```

To use client name include following in you client model

```
class Klient(models.Model):
    ...model fields
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

replace name with the field which stores client name

Comment: It wasn't exactly that but about ForeignKey it returns the entire 'Client' object. How do I display the company name only? The main problem in my question is the automatic completion of the NIP field based on the selected company field. This is my first Django project so I don't fully understand everything. Please be understanding

Comment: check the answer now, i have updated it and from where do  you want to get the NIP value, means where have stored it to  be matched with the company name.

Comment: Yep, work fine with company name in dropdown. Still looking for answers how to automatically complete the next field after selecting from the dropdown.

Comment: where is the nip value stored which you wan to be matched with company name and fill it in the form.

Comment: if you store nip value in the klient model then you don't need to add this field again in the Faktura model as you have already linked it to  the klient model by foreign key. You can use it in your templates wherever you need.